# How to use the word "mainstream" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, articles

Should we use "the" before the word "mainstream"? I have found some sentences on the internet and not sure if they are right and if they right then not sure why they are right without the word "the."

1. Many North Americans use alternative therapies along with mainstream medicine to treat illnesses.
2. This notion was largely overlooked in mainstream psychology for many years.

Answer (score 3):

As a noun, you would use the article referring a specific context:

***[(the) mainstream](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mainstream)​:***

> - the way of life or set of beliefs accepted by most people:
>
>   - The new law should allow more disabled people ***to enter the mainstream of American life.***
>   - ***In the mainstream of modern literature.***

As an adjective, as in your examples, it is used to refer to standard , general context, and the article is not generally used:

***Mainstream:***

> - considered normal, and having or using ideas, beliefs, etc. that are accepted by most people:
>
>   - *This is the director's **first mainstream Hollywood film.***
>   - *Children with minor handicaps would be able to **attend mainstream schools***

(Cambridge Dictionary)